# std::unordered_map with 5 uint32_t as keys

Tags: performance, hash

I am writing a checkers engine that fails catastrophically when there's a hash collision. The simplest (and sufficient for my needs) way to fix this would be to use the entire position as a hash key. A position is determined by five uint32_t bitboards and a binary player indicator (which is also a uint32_t). Whats the best way to have std::unordered_map take a 6-tuple of uint32_t as a key?

Comment: please don't ask the same question again [std::unordered_map with 256 bit keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59308754/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::unordered\_map with 256 bit keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308754/stdunordered-map-with-256-bit-keys)